# Transfer in Atlanta

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, atl

We are travelling from Manchester UK to Miami via Atlanta in March to connect with a cruise. Our flights have been booked by Princess cruises. They are insistent that a layover time of 1hour 25 mins is sufficient to pass through security etc and connect with our delta flight to Miami. Will we make it ! Also who is responsible for getting us to Miami in time to board our cruise ship?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same ticket? What are the date and times, including the latest time you can board your cruise?

Comment: If the flights are booked on a single ticket then he airline is responsible for getting you to your destination if you miss your connection.  If the cruise line booked the flights then the cruise line should be responsible for any problems that arise because of delays caused by the airline.  Nobody can tell you whether you will make your connection because nobody knows whether you will arrive in Atlanta at the scheduled time.

Comment: I have travelled to Atlanta a lot (often from Manchester) but not since before Covid so I am not up to date and not posting an answer.  I don't transfer but, as others say, you have to clear immigration and customs even if you do.  If I am in my rental car less than 2 hours after landing then I regard that as good.  I would be nervous if I were you.  So, as others advise, check with the cruise what happens if you miss your connection.  In some airports (around the world), I have seen staff help to assist people with tight connections but I have not seen that in Atlanta.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming this is a single ticket. Two separate tickets are a clear non-starter here.

> They are insistent that a layover time of 1hour 25 mins is sufficient

Delta's minimum connection time in Atlanta for international to domestic is 85 minutes, so it's right on the edge of a legal connection.

Since Atlanta is your first point of entry in the US you need to go through immigration, collect your bags, go through customs, drop your bags again after customs, go to your departure terminal, go through security, go to your gate.

If everything operates normally, this is doable but there isn't a whole lot of room for error (delayed first leg, long lines at immigration, lost bag, long line at security, etc.)

> Will we make it?

No one knows for sure. I think you have a good chance of making it, but there is also a non-trivial chance that you won't. A lot depends on your specific details. Things that speed up a connection are: flying business, status with the airlines, Global Entry, TSA PreCheck, no checked luggage, etc)

> Also who is responsible for getting us to Miami

The airline is. If you miss the connection (through no fault of your own), they will put you on the next available flight to Miami. Delta has 8 non-stops a day Atlanta to Miami.

> in time to board our cruise ship?

That's a tricky one. The airline has the obligation to get you to Miami, but they can't guarantee a specific time. Since the cruise company booked the ticket, they probably have some process to deal with delays. This may include flying to the first stop after Miami, if you can't get to Miami on time or expediting your pick up from the airport.

I would look at the Delta ATL-<MIA schedule for that day and check with ones would get you there on time. If there are one or two later flights that would work as well, then there is no harm in staying with the short connection. If all goes well you make it and have more time in Miami. If you don't, you just take the next flight.

If the short connection is the only option that still makes the cruise, I would call the cruise company and ask what happens if you miss it.

Comment: According to my quick Google, Manchester has TSA pre-clearance.  I don't have experience with that, but it could affect your answer.

Comment: Not according to the CBP website: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance . But then again the CBP is not known for proactively keeping their websites up to date.

Comment: I'm probably wrong.  I went back and re-googled, and all the links I looked at ([like this](https://www.routesonline.com/news/29/breaking-news/249250/ten-more-airports-to-offer-preclearance-for-us-flights/)) were from 2015, and when reading more deeply only mentioned "being discussed".